Does a cube under high pressure transform into a ball?
Will a material in the shape of a cube, under high pressure, crumble into the shape of a ball?
One would expect that there will develop strains and stresses, after which the corners crumble and eventually you are left with a ball. But at the same time I find it hard to imagine that a cube collapses at the bottom of the deepest ocean.
What will happen, assuming that the properties (reactions to pressure) of the material are the same in every direction? And what if this is not the case?

For a symmetric crystal, it retains its shape.

Is the cube solid or hollow? Currently you seem to have received some answers assuming a solid cube (e.g. from Chemomechanics) and others assuming a hollow cube (e.g. from KDP).

@JonCuster To post an answer, please use the answer box instead of the comment box. To post a brief answer, use the answer box but don't type very much in it.

@JonCuster I don't think so. Not for all pressures. For example, put it in the center of a neutron star.

Personally, I do not think you have done and shown sufficient work in this post as it is required by the rules of this website. Physics is not speculative in nature, it speaks the language of mathematics. I think you had to derive a mathematical model for your situation and analyze it to answer the question you posted. Most likely, the analysis would be very difficult. Then you could post your question and ask about the specific part of your analysis procedure that you didn't know how to proceed with.

This is easiest to answer if you imagine something really easily deformable, like a lump of clay. The clay's shape can be changed just by applying a fairly small net force to any part of it.
What happens if we shape the clay into a cube, put it into a pressure chamber, and start dialling up the pressure? To a good approximation, the clay itself is incompressible, so we don't expect it to change its size. But there is a lot of force at the boundary of the clay, so we might expect it to start deforming.
However, because the clay is incompressible, the pressure inside the clay has also increased, and in fact it is the same as the pressure outside it. So although there is a force pushing inwards from the boundary there is also an equal and opposite force pushing outwards from inside. As a result, there is no net force being applied to any part of the clay, so it doesn't change shape. This is as true at the corners as it is on the faces - every part of the clay is at the same pressure as every part of the water, so there is no net force acting anywhere.
What if the clay is compressible? In that case, it will compress until its internal pressure matches that of the water outside it. If the material is isotropic (behaves the same in all directions) and homogeneous (behaves the same everywhere) then the cube will just shrink evenly everywhere - it changes size but not shape.
Objects like polystyrene cups deform considerably under pressure, but this is because they are not isotropic and homogeneous. But solid objects generally don't change shape at all unless they have a compressible part, such as an air chamber inside them.

Even a polystyrene cup can 'compress' without significant distortion depending on how it is manufactured. Family member was on a ship doing sea-floor surveying in very deep ocean. One 'trick' was to attach a couple of polystyrene coffee cups with the probe before it was sent down. At pressure the individual cells collapse and any gas in the diffuses out. On return, the cup was about the size of a thimble but still cup-shaped.

Why are large planets almost perfectly spherical instead of some other shape even if they are composed of solid materials? It is possible to make an analogy with the cube, only that the pressure comes from the gravitational field and not from something external. The sphere would always be the shape minimising the potential energy of the object.

@Flyingfenix As I understand it, there are two key differences for astronomical objects: nothing is isotropic, homogenous, or incompressible at the scale of a planet, and because the forces on a planet come from its own self-gravity rather than external pressure, the net forces on a point near the surface are not perfectly balanced (as you describe in your own answer; but that is wrong for external pressure).

@Flyingfenix for a planet, pressure is not the only force acting, there is gravity as well. If a planet has a giant mountain sticking up into space then the pressure under the mountain is higher than the pressure under the surrounding lowlands, due to the mountain's weight. That pressure difference exerts a net force on the rocks under the mountain, and if that force is big enough the rock will deform, allowing the mountain to sink. The same thing happens on a smaller scale - a giant cube of wet clay will slump into a flatter shape. This is due to the gravitational force, not just pressure.

@zwol, please point me why it is different if the force on the object comes from being uniformly applied from the inside instead of being uniformly applied from the outside.

@Flyingfenix The short version is that self-gravity isn't uniform, it falls off as $1/r^2$ with distance from the center of mass. The long version deserves to be its own question.

Pressure changes the size of a uniform material, not its shape.
More generally, a stress field is the sum of a dilatational or hydrostatic stress and a deviatoric stress. The former is equitriaxial—that is, it comprises equal normal stresses oriented to the three Cartesian axes, however they are defined. It tends to change the material’s volume, as mediated by the bulk modulus. The latter is everything else; it tends to distort the material (and also is considered the source of failure in predominant models). Pressure corresponds to the former.
So we can expect a single-material cube to shrink but not to round when pressurized. In a symmetric crystal, the molecular spacing is reduced uniformly. (If the cube isn’t a uniform material, different parts may shrink to different degrees, inducing deviatoric stress and resulting in distortion. So a metal sphere with closed-cell-foam tips to make up the final shape of a cube at atmospheric pressure would indeed start to resemble a ball upon pressurization, as the sphere would shrink only minimally compared to the foam.)

Is this uniformity generally true for finite deformations as well?  Or does it rely on Hooke's Law in some way?

One could discard Hooke’s law and still rely on a continuum model, free-body diagrams of regions of the cube, and symmetry reasoning to argue that the molecular spacing near the corner of the cube should change in concert with that near the center of the cube, for example.

Not a ball, but high pressure can certainly alter the structure of a material at a molecular level.
An excellent illustration of this is Ice.
As the Wikipedia page linked show, Ice under varying conditions, primarily different pressures and temperatures, has a large number of quite different structures associated with its different phases.
On a larger scale, gravitational forces will tend to bring objects into a spherical state (or more like a deformed sphere due to rotational effects).  Smaller asteroids do not show such symmetry, but as you get larger, more symmetry appears.
And if enough pressure does exist you get quite different phenomena, like neutron stars and white dwarfs.
Different material have different phases and behaviors and it's not a one-size-fits all rule.

If the cube is hollow, the cube will end up with its faces dished inwards something like this:

This is because the edges tend to be stronger due to the geometrical properties of folded edges as illustrated by this folded piece of paper:

An ever better example of the how folded edges can multiply the strength and rigidity of a surface material can be seen in this video of miura folded paper.
When the pressure on the inside of a cube is higher than the pressure outside the cube, the faces will bulge outwards to form something approximating a sphere. When the pressure on the outside exceeds the inside pressure, the faces will curve inwards. It can be observed that the natural tendency of a surface is to be concave on the high pressure side and convex on the low pressure side.
At extreme pressures like at the bottom of the ocean, the edges might eventually crumple, the most likely scenario is that the material in the flat faces becomes stretched and thinned out as the faces dish inward and as the face stretches it becomes weaker and the most likely failure mode is that one or more of the faces rupture.
This is why deep sea submersibles tend to be spherical or a cylindrical with hemispherical caps, so that flat surfaces are avoided, because they do not resist pressure very well.
P.S. In response to the Chemomechanics comment, I have made it clear I was assuming the cube is hollow. If the cube is solid, I agree with the answers that say the cube will shrink uniformly and retain its cubical shape. Either way, the cube does not transform to a sphere under extreme pressure except in contrived circumstance where the cube is specifically designed to transform into a sphere under pressure.

You seem to be describing the behavior of a hollow cube.

@Chemomechanics The OP did not specify a hollow or solid cube. Yes, I was assuming a hollow cube. I was assuming the context was the design of  submersibles, which are usually hollow to allow passengers. I do agree that if the cube is solid it will tend to shrink in size rather than change shape. Either way, I do not think the the cube will transform to a sphere.

I once built a cubic-foot vacuum chamber from acrylic and perhaps skimped on the wall thickness a bit. Your first image serves as an embarrassing reminder. My colleagues took one look and walked right out of the lab.

@Chemomechanics if noone was (seriously) hurt it was an educational experiment.

Newbie here. Please follow my reasoning. Probably flawed somewhere, so please point me where.
No material is perfectly incompressible and no material has infinite strength. Given that...
Take a point exactly in the center of the (perfect) cube under pressure. Being perfectly symmetrical, there is no net force on it regardless of the external pressure since for any direction (vector?) chosen there will be another opposite force with the exact opposite direction and equal intensity.
Now, take a point infinitesimally close to one of the vertexes of the cube. It receives external forces from every side except one (pointing to the center of the cube). At this point the net forces aren't symmetrical.
For any other point of the cube closer to its center the forces still aren't symmetrical, but the difference is smaller as there is more of the "cube" supporting it.
If this asymmetry is larger than the physical resistance of the bonds between the particles of the material, then these bonds will break and the particle will be moved closer to the center of the cube.
In the end, given enough pressure, it will reach the shape that provides no new pathways to "be closer to the center", i.e. a sphere.
Of course, if we are talking about normal solids, the pressures required would be astronomical (literally, probably...), but since this wasn't specified, this would be the most generic possible answer.

I believe this answer is correct for an object being compressed by its own self-gravity (e.g. a planet) but not for an object being compressed externally; the asymmetry you describe exists because self-gravity falls off as $1/r^2$ from the center of mass, producing a gradient which is absent for uniform external pressure.

If you look at a flat part of the cube very close to the corner, it's not being pushed towards the center, it's being pushed towards the opposite side. The parts near the corners are being pushed the same as the rest of the face. This results in the cube retaining it's shape even at high pressures.

@zwol, your conclusion is correct, but the reason for the asymmetry is that pressure acts perpendicular to the surface while gravity always pulls towards the center. Gravity could fall off ay any power (including not falling off at all) and it would still result in a sphere being the shape matter got pulled into as long as gravity always pulled to the center of mass.

@Eph Huh, so it doesn't matter if there's a gradient or not? ("no gradient" in the sense that $\nabla\phi = 0$ everywhere)

@zwol My point (no pun intended) is that at the very tip of the cube the internal force countering the external pressure is bore by less chemical/electrostatic/mechanical bonds while at other points of the surface or under the surface there are more. Since these bonds have limited strength, I think at some level of pressure they will break and the particle will relocate to some other point with lower potential energy, that being closer to the center where there will be more bonds or bonds more stable than at the tip.

@Flyingfenix the very tip will likely be rounded off on any shape before any pressure is applied, but if it's something like a silicon crystal it could come to a single atom that has  two or three bonds to it's closest neighbors rather than the usual four. Those bonds would be under compression on average because of the pressure the external atoms apply, but it would be no more compression then the rest of the bonds in the whole feel. All of the interior bonds also apply compression such that if you cut the object in half, the exterior pressure could exactly replace the internal pressure.

Let me try another approach to this question with a purely mechanical and statistical view.
TL;DR: The cube will still turn into a sphere when under pressure since it is the shape where the particles have the highest binding energy and the lowest degrees of freedom.
The long explanation:
First applying some simplifications and assumptions. Not a cube anymore, but an extremely long (in comparison with the size of the particles) line of single particles in an infinite bidimensional space. The particles per se are perfect spheres with definite mass and incompressible, but the connections between them are perfectly elastic, have a definite, finite length at rest and have finite maximum strength (i.e they have a maximum length) but they never break from compression. If the connections are strained beyond their maximum strength they'll break and the particle will be free. After the bond is broken there is no more forces between the particles but bonds may re-form (see below)
Each particle can form zero or more connections to other particles but the number of connections is limited by the closest packing of the particles given their size. All connections between particles have the same strength (but different particle configurations apart from perfectly regular packings will leave bonds more or less strained).
A free particle will re-form a bond if its distance to other particles of the same type is smaller than the distance corresponding to the energy that was necessary to break an analogous bond.
Pressure is applied as the result of random collisions from perfect non-bound particles traveling to/from an infinite distance (in comparison to the size of the line) - more pressure implies more and stronger collisions (energy distribution of the colliding particles follows thermodynamic laws). The collisions are perfectly elastic.
There is no internal relaxation mechanism (i.e. all mechanical energy remains as mechanical energy and may only be "dissipated" through other collisions) and no hysteresis. There is no other interaction mechanism besides purely mechanical collisions between the particles causing the pressure and the particles of the line and the elastic properties of the bonds.
Bonds rotate perfectly around the spheres meaning that there is no "tethering" of the bond to any particular point of the circular outline of the sphere.
For each particle not at the tip of the line, there will always be two bonds, therefore any collision with the external particles will have to overcome at most twice the maximum bond strength, so the colliding particle will have to have at most twice the energy.
For each particle at the tip, the energy needed to break the particle apart from the line is one half at most compared to other particles inside the line.
At low pressures the energy of the particles is statistically "never" high enough to break bonds between particles.
At higher pressures the colliding particles may have high enough energy to break apart particles from the tips of the line. If this is the case, what will happen to the freed particle?
a) If the particle comes from the half-sphere pointing inside the line from the point of view of the particle that was at the tip, it will be ejected towards the line where it may interact with other particles of the line forming new bonds.
a2) The bond may be not broken but the collision may impart enough momentum to rotate the particle putting it inside the distance of other particles allowing it to form another bond.
b) If the particle comes from the opposite half-sphere pointing outside the line, it will be ejected and lost "forever".
Now for the particles inside the line...
c) For side collisions with particles inside the line, even if the energy is not enough to break any bonds, it may bend the line enough to put other two particles close enough to form additional bonds, "clumping" them.
d) If the energy is enough to break one or more bonds, the line is broken and the fragments may or may not get close enough to re-form bonds. At an extreme case the two fragments spin and approach side-by-side where all particles form new bonds...
d2) It doesn't matter if the line is broken in two segments that drift infinitely apart since the line is considered infinite related to the size of their particles. It is the same as starting the process again.
Since the chance of the event "a", "c" and "d" happening is above zero and is above "b" ("b" and "d2" doesn't matter since the line can be considered infinite), one may conclude that at some pressure definitely bonds will be broken and reformed in a more stable configuration (i.e. more than one or two). That is after some infinite amount of time the line will turn into a perfectly packed array of spheres contained in a circle.
The line will always end up reconfigured into something where the particles have less degrees of freedom and have the maximum amount of bonds between them.
Extending this reasoning to a 2D plane of particles or any non-spherical 3D shape and a 3D space it turns out that the most stable configuration will always be a sphere and will always exist a pressure above which there will be enough particle reconfiguration to change its shape.
Therefore, if OP's cube was made of the matter described in this exercise, definitely increasing the pressure beyond some value would turn it into a sphere.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

"For each particle at the tip, the energy needed to break the particle apart from the line is one half at most compared to other particles inside the line." is quite misleading as only one bond needs to break to change the configuration. Additionally collisions with the right half pulling it right and collisions with the left half pulling it left could all impart energy  in the form of momentum that contribute to a bond breaking, thus making it actually easier to break the line than the tip.

Additionally, you're making up new laws of physics in your assumptions. "Bonds rotate perfectly around the spheres meaning that there is no "tethering" of the bond to any particular point of the circular outline of the sphere." this does not happen in reality, and only is a good approximation when the thermal energy is high enough for the molecules/particles to slide past each other. This results in the liquid state of matter. So, this answer is basically describing why liquids form spheres, which happens at low pressures just as well as at high pressure.

In a cube under pressure, the sides and corners are more flexible and will deflect more, following Poisson's effect (this applies to elastic materials, that is, to most all materials in the real world), but the middle part of the cube deflects less because it is limited laterally by the side material.  source
The fact that the sides are under the same pressure is irrelevant here; in order for the sides not to bulge out, they must be mechanically constrained.
However, because of the tendency of the surface of each side of the cube to maintain its geometry, the cube would deform roughly into a round lump with 12 edges protruding out like fins. One way to imagine this shape is to put an apple in a cubic plastic bag and then vacuum the bag.

Poisson's ratio can be used to find the relationship between a stress tensor and strain tensor. However, in this case, the stress tensor is isotropic and shear free. For isotropic materials (many materials, and all materials for which there's a singular Poisson's ratio) this results in a isotropic shear free strain tensor i.e. it only compresses but does not change shape.
